# com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable in thread stack trace and hibernate connection does not get established

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, c3p0

I encountered the issue when I upgraded my hibernate lib from hibernate 3 to hibernate core 4.3.6 and added c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar along with it. My hibernate connection doesn't get established. In the thread stack trace getting following:

```
"pool-9-thread-11" prio=6 tid=0x00000000147dd000 nid=0xd20 in Object.wait() [0x0000000018dee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000701ac0608> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1414)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    - locked <0x0000000701ac0608> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - 0x00000007b5530978> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add:

```
c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar
```

You should add the hibernate-c3p0 dependency instead, and let Maven figure all needed dependencies for you:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

So after setting this dependency and running mvn:dependency:tree, you should get something like:

```
D:\wrk\vladmihalcea\hibernate-master-class\core>mvn dependency:tree
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] 'usePluginRegistry' is deprecated and has no effect. @ C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\conf\settings.xml
[WARNING]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hibernate-master-class-core 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ hibernate-master-class-core ---
[INFO] com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-master-class-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttddyy:datasource-proxy:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The hibernate-c3p0 brings also com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1 and com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is some dependency on com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources which is present in c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar. If i remove c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar I get "Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources" error

Regards, Ankit

Comment: Check my updated answer. You should be fine with that dependency.

Comment: i set c3p0 property checkoutTimeout =300000 which solved the problem. This property sets the number of milliseconds a client calling getConnection() will wait for a Connection to be checked-in or acquired when the pool is exhausted. So i am not sure whether this is the correct way or not...Please suggest

Comment: [The default value](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#checkoutTimeout) is to wait indefinitely, so it's strange that setting it fixed your problem.

Comment: I already have org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.3.6.Final with  com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4 and com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1(which is nothing but c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar).

Comment: Yup default value is to wait indefinitely. By setting this value to be 30000 I am not getting thread in waiting state . Also hibernate queries run as expected which actually stopped when i encountered this issue.